# opencart pagination without database

Tags: php, database, pagination, opencart

Is there anyway I can implement the pagination class in opencart without making a call to the database?
How could I control the limit on the products being shown in the view. I'm trying to paginate a long list of products before they're inserted into the database from a csv parse and import class I have written for opencart. The code below is what I'm trying to get around, this is code from the model limiting the products to the view, I need to do this with the array that the csv parser outputs.

```
   if (isset($data['start']) || isset($data['limit'])) {
        if ($data['start'] < 0) {
            $data['start'] = 0;
        }               

        if ($data['limit'] < 1) {
            $data['limit'] = 20;
        }   

        $sql .= " LIMIT " . (int)$data['start'] . "," . (int)$data['limit'];
    }
```

any ideas would be greatly appreciated!! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for a `for` loop:

```
$demo_array = file('your_file.csv'); // load your csv

$start = $data['start']; // e.g. 0
$limit = $data['limit']; // e.g. 20

for($i = $start; $i < $limit; $i++) {
    // process this result using $i as the array key
    // var_dump($demo_array[$i]);
}
```

> Docs

- http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php

Comment: thank you, now i just have to implement it within opencart. It makes sense to me what i need to do now though but i still have a ways to go. So i would need to use this loop within the view to limit the array output?

Comment: Yes, although ideally you would use the start and limit parameters to specify where you start and stop reading the file. This would be important for you if your CSV file was large, but this method is the easiest in the short term.